# On the semisimple eigenvectors of a matrix-valued function A(t) and its limit

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a follow-up question from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4138512/on-the-eigenvectors-of-a-matrix-valued-function-at-and-its-limit/4138829#4138829).

In *Lax, Linear Algebra and its Applications* the following theorem is presented (Ch. 9.3, Thm. 12, p. 137). I believe that a similar statements can be found in Kato's perturbation theory.

> Let $A(t)$ be a differentiable function of the real variable $t$ whose values are self-adjoint matrices. Suppose that at $t = 0$, $A(0)$ has an eigenvalue $a_0$ of multiplicity $k > 1$. Denote by $\mathcal{N}$ the eigenspace of $A(0)$ with eigenvalue $a_0$, and by $P$ the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{N}$. Assume that the self-adjoint mapping $P\dot{A}(0)P$ of $\mathcal{N}$ into $\mathcal{N}$ has $k$ distinct eigenvalues $d_i$, $i = 1,\dots, k$. Denote by $w_i$ corresponding normalized eigenvectors. Then for $t$ small enough, $A(t)$ has $k$ eigenvalues $a(t)$, $j = 1,\dots,k$, near $a_0$, with the following properties:
>
> 1. $a_i(t)$ depend differentiably on $t$ and tend to $a_0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.
> 2. For $t\neq 0$, the $a_j(t)$ are distinct.
> 3. The corresponding eigenvector $h_j(t)$, $A(t)h_j(t)=a_j(t)h_j(t)$, can be so normalized that $h_j(t)$ tends to $w_i$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

I am particularly confused about points 1. and 2. and the use of indices in $a_i$ and $a_j$ as well $w_i$ in 3. It is probably easiest to illustrate my confusion using an example:

$$
A(t) = VDV^T+tI\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3},\quad \dot{A}(t)=A(0),\quad V^T V= I,\quad D=\text{diag}(1,1,2)
$$
Partition $V$ as $V=[v_1,v_2,v_3]$, then $\mathcal{N}=\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$ and $P=[v_1,v_2][v_1,v_2]^T$ associated with eigenvalue $a_0=1$ and multiplicity $k=2$. $P\dot{A}(0)P$ has two distinct eigenvalues: $d_1=0$ with $w_1=v_3$ and $d_{2,3}=1$ with $w_2=v_1$ and $w_3=v_2$. Note that all matrices share the same eigenvectors and e.g. a possible choice is $v_i(t)=v_i$, $i=1,\dots,3$.

From point 1., I understand that the eigenvalues $1+t$ tend to $a_0$.

**Questions:**

- In point 2., which eigenvalues is he referring to in my example?
- In point 3., I would have expected a statement like $v_1(t)\rightarrow w_2$ for $t\rightarrow 0$. How does this point apply to my example?
- In my example, the eigenvectors of $A(0)$ and $P\dot{A}(0)P$ can be chosen to be the same. In general, how are the eigenvectors of $A(0)$ and $P\dot{A}(0)P$ related? I believe that for symmetric $A(t)$ they must always share *some* eigenvectors.